# TFS organization in large companies (TFS 2012)

Tags: architecture, projects-and-solutions, solution

everyone

I want sugestions about that scenario:

50 persons working in a large e-commerce portal. About 35 devs, 10 QAs, 5 managers, or anything like this. Those devs are divided in teams with specific roles, like front-end team, back-end team, and so on... We have daily publishes in the production environment, and these code published include bug-fixes and new features.

Each Developer is working in new features or in bug-fixes and this can involve different silos or impact them. Today in TFS we working on 2 differents collections and on dozens of differents Team Projects. Despite that, all work is organized by work items in a specific team Project for that.

In this company, the code is approved by QA before go to production and all code integration, merges and deploys are responsability of a team called ALM (4 persons full time in this work)

My question is about how do you organize this mess, thinking in TFS as the source control system. How can I structure my branchs strategy to support this scenario and how to make a branch strategy that support a future continous delivery? I need some clues e some debate around new ideas to improve my team's productivity and avoid errors in the code that I publish to production enviroment.

Thanks!

Comment: Branches is one solution, but it's usuallly messy. Whenever possible try to create your application in such a way that you can toggle features that are not yet done. Or that they are installed as plugins to the main application. That gives you a lot easier workflow in terms of merges and configuration. Branching is usually not about improves productivity. It's about shielding eachother from changes and integrating late vs early.

Comment: Toggle features are great tecnical tool, but I can't toggle the correction of a bug, right? Or if my new feature affect many files, this toggle will going to be a big mess in my code, correct? But, despite this, I know that I have so many tecnical debts in my solutions and because of this toggle features will be a pain... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is broad scenario...and tough to answer exactly. I would do appropriate branching and automate the processes as much as possible. Part IV: *Large Project Considerations* of the guide "Team Development with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" addresses similar issue and available as (free) download at http://tfsguide.codeplex.com/

As per this scenario, you would find below presentation very helpful:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2013-the-Netherlands/From-Continuous-Integration-to-Continuous-Delivery-with-Visual-Studio-Team-Foundation-Server-2012

Hope those resources will help you to take informed decisions. Thanks.

Comment: Might as well add the ALM Rangers Branchnig Guidance: http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/